# escaping nested FQL statements in Graph API URL

Tags: facebook, url, escaping, facebook-fql

using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) I generate and test FQL statements like this ***simple one***

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()
```

I can convert it to an URL for stand alone usage.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()&access_token=...
```

This ***works*** without any problems and also the other version of escaping works:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%3Dme%28%29&access_token=...
```

---

But a ***more complex query*** like this

```
SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me())
```

works only in the Graph API Explorer directly, but not as an URL.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+src_big+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id+IN+(SELECT+object_id+FROM+photo_tag+WHERE+subject=me())&access_token=...
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20src_big%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20object_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20photo_tag%20WHERE%20subject%3Dme%28%29%29&access_token=...
```

both versions for the nested query produce the following ***error***

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected 'SELECT' at position 46.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 601
   }
}
```

And ideas what I am doing wrong? I test these URLs via using the address bar in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I do not use firefox but e.g. Node.js it works:

```
var https = require('https');

var access_token = '...';
var FQL_query = 'SELECT+src_big+FROM+photo+WHERE+object_id+IN+(SELECT+object_id+FROM+photo_tag+WHERE+subject=me())';

//this works as well
//var FQL_query = 'SELECT%20src_big%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20object_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20photo_tag%20WHERE%20subject%3Dme%28%29%29';

var options = {
  hostname: 'graph.facebook.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/fql?q=' + FQL_query + '&access_token=' + access_token,
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

So this is solved for me. Sorry for the unnecessary question. ;)